# Когда предложения противопоставлены по содержанию?

Tags: егэ

> (1) Певучесть формы привлекает внимание людей, ещё не зная, какая
>   ценность скрыта в художественном создании, люди безотчётно влекутся к
>   нему и воспринимают его ради его внешних чар. (2) Но вместе с тем
>   блестящая кора скрывает от них глубину,  делает её недоступной; в этом
>   -- мудрая хитрость природы.

Судя по моему пособию, предложения (1) и (2) *противопоставлены по содержанию*. Почему это так? В первом предложении говорится, что **привлекает людей форма** (худож. произведения), а во втором говорится, что **эта форма скрывает богатое содержание**. Как я понимаю, если бы в первом говорилось, что форма привлекает людей, а во втором -- что форма НЕ привлекает людей, тогда они были бы противопоставлены по содержанию.

Comment: См. [Противительные отношения](http://www.interword.se/Syntax/Lektionsmaterial/GVOZDEV/s/stil624.htm).

Comment: "внимание людей, ещё не зная". Здесь пауза должна быть значительнее, чем запятая: от тчк-зпт до тире.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Косвенно противопоставлены положительный и отрицательный моменты привлекательности формы художественного произведения. C одной стороны, привлекательная форма - это хорошо, поскольку она делает произведение востребованным (**привлекает** больше людей), с другой стороны это плохо, поскольку она же препятствует донесению до людей глубинной сути произведения: часть людей её не воспримет и будет довольствоваться тем, что от этой сути **отвлекает**.

Answer (score 2):

Автор всегда стремится донести до читателей содержание книги, это его главная и конечная цель.

Красивая форма, с одной стороны, вызывает интерес к произведению (у произведения появляется шанс быть прочитанным), а с другой - мешает пониманию его содержания, то есть достижению конечной цели.